# Another GridBagLayout Alignment

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I read a lot about this problem here... But I just don't seem to get how to solve this.
All the solutions I tried are not working.

But let's start at the beginning:
I'm building my interface with Swing and trying to be modular.
So I've got a class (extending JPanel) for my left Main Menu.
The Menu is built with several buttons in a GridBagLayout.

But I am not able to get this layout to aligned to the top of the window (panel).
Example: Label at the Top of the Panel, Text Field below, button below the text field, etc.

Please see my code:

```
public class LeftMenu extends JPanel {
  public LeftMenu(){

    GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[] { 86, 0 };
    gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[] {32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32 };
    gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    setLayout(gbl_panel);

    JLabel lblEnterTrunkId = new JLabel("Enter Trunk ID");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblEnterTrunkId = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.gridy = 0;
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    add(lblEnterTrunkId, gbc_lblEnterTrunkId);
    }
 }
```

There is a text field and some buttons following behind the Label.
But I assume, these are not relevant...
If they are... they are mostly looking like the Label (just that they are not Labels... I think you get me)

All guides I read, are all pointing to the anchor of the GridBagConstraint. It is there.... but not working.
It's wonderfully aligned in the middle of the panel.

If it does matter:
the Panel ist used as a LeftComponent of a SplitPane:

```
public LeftMenu leftpanel = new LeftMenu(); 

splitPaneTrunks.setLeftComponent(leftpanel);
```

Looking forward to your help.

Here is a picture of my side menu... centered horizontally. as it should not be.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsBg2.png]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: show HorizontalLayout in swingx library

Comment: I suspect that the enclosining element isn't using it's full vertical space. One thing I do to help with problems like this is to set the background color of all the panels in the hierarchy to different colors. This makes some kinds of layout problems obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `GridBagLayout`, you could make a wrap using a `JPanel` with the layout `BorderLayout`, like so:

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel gridBagWrap = new JPanel();

    GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[] { 86, 0 };
    gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[] {32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32 };
    gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    gridBagWrap.setLayout(gbl_panel);

    JLabel lblEnterTrunkId = new JLabel("Enter Trunk ID");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblEnterTrunkId = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.gridy = 0;
    gbc_lblEnterTrunkId.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gridBagWrap.add(lblEnterTrunkId, gbc_lblEnterTrunkId);

    add(gridBagWrap, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... seems I described a bit wrong what I need... edited my text. Sorry about this. I do not want to align the objects at the top of the page. The whole gridbag should align at the top. All elements in the gridbag are positioned tonather exactly as I need it... but the first object is not at the top of the JPanel.

Comment: @Marcus can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Just did it... was not aware, that it could be added here so easily.

Comment: Just tell me why I didn't think of this??? Works like a charm. Thanks for your help. I really should think more about wrapping the different elements as needed.

Comment: @Marcus if this answer solved your issue, press the tick to mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

> here is a picture of my side menu... centered horizontally. as it should not be.

I think you mean it should not be centered vertically if you want the components displayed from the top.

In any case I think the problem is your `weighty` constraint. It needs to be non-zero for at least one of the components otherwise the components will be centered vertically.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). There is a section on the weightx/weighty constraints that will explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no surprise that you are lost with `GridBagLayout` manager. 
It is in fact one of its most commonly mentioned features. `GridBagLayout` comes from the nineties and uses pixel-fixed gaps between components, which is not portable. With this manager, you have to tediously define each cell of the layout; no wonder people are confused.

I recommend to use `MigLayout`. And if it cannot be used, then `GroupLayout`.

Here is a solution with `MigLayout`:

```
package com.zetcode;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/*
Demonstration of MigLayout manager.
Author: Jan Bodnar
Website: zetcode.com
 */
public class MigLayoutTrunkEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutTrunkEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Enter Trunk ID");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("A");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("B");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("C");
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("D");
        JButton btn5 = new JButton("E");

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20, 25);
        area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        JLabel statusBar = new JLabel("Ready");

        createLayout(lbl, textField, btn1, btn2, btn3,
                btn4, btn5, area, statusBar);

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[align center]", ""));

        add(arg[0], "split 7, flowy");
        add(arg[1]);
        add(arg[2]);
        add(arg[3]);
        add(arg[4]);
        add(arg[5]);
        add(arg[6]);
        add(arg[7], "grow, push, wrap");
        add(arg[8], "align left, growx, spanx");

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutTrunkEx ex = new MigLayoutTrunkEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

It is easy, once you get to know `MigLayout`. Ten or fifteen minutes of work.

Screenshot:

[image: MigLayout example screenshot]